# Audio & Video chat in Asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrtc, videochat

Hello i am looking for a method to implement audio and video chat in my asp.net webs application, i have tried with webRTC with xsocket but it's not working, and there is another problem that i wanted this feature in local host not on server like browser to browser, is this possible or not, so can any body point me in the right direction????

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k4GrUWCUQ8

this is the video that i have tried but getting some errors.